# Linq To Data set error System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataset

I get the following exception using Linq to data set "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

The problem is as follows I have a model with two value of type int?. The values in the database are not required so some fields are blank. I have read the table into a data set and now I need to query the data set using the following code.

```
//model
public class Model
{
    // Public Properties
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public int? YearBegin { get; set; }
    public int? YearEnd { get; set; }
}

//query
var list = from m in data.Tables["Models"].AsEnumerable()
select new Model
{
   // rest of members omitted to simplify
   YearBegin = m.Field<int>("YearBegin"), 
   YearEnd =   m.Field<int>("YearEnd") 
};
```

I have tried the following none have worked:

```
m.Field<int?>("YearBegin")
YearEnd = m.IsNull("YearEnd") ? null, m.Field<int>("YearEnd")
```

Is there another way to check if the field has a value similar to String.IsNullOrEmpty().
Using string as the type is not a possibility...

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried 'YearBegin = m.Field<int?>("YearBegin")'? Did you get the same error?

Comment: Yes the same error. m.IsNull("YearEnd") seems to return true all the time also.

Comment: While your model may have the fields as an int, what is the databases underlying column type? The invalid cast may be because you're trying to convert incompatible types (like Oracle loves to return Number columns as decimal). It's also possible that the columns are Date/DateTime in which case you'd need to cast to a DateTime and extract the Year property.

Comment: Problem solved, I am working against a legacy access database and the data type was stored as Integer instead on Long Integer meaning it is represented as an Int16 in the data set hence the Invalid cast exception...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using a typed DataSet, so my first question would be is the does the DataTable know that those fields are supposed to be 'int?' in the first place, or are they listed as strings? If the DataTable is treating those fields as strings, you will experience that error. The following code assumes a TestData DataSet with a Models DataRow, with two nullable string columns as YearBegin and YearEnd:

```
using (TestData ds = new TestData())
{
      // Typed Rows
      ds.Models.AddModelsRow("1", "2");
      ds.Models.AddModelsRow(ds.Models.NewModelsRow()); // NULL INFO TEST
      // Untyped rows
      DataRow r = ds.Models.NewRow();
      r[0] = "4";
      r[1] = "5";
      ds.Models.Rows.Add(r);


      //query
      var list = from m in ds.Tables["Models"].AsEnumerable()
                 select new Model
                 {
                     // rest of members omitted to simplify
                     YearBegin = m.Field<int?>("YearBegin"),
                     YearEnd = m.Field<int?>("YearEnd"),
                 };
}
```

That code will encounter the InvalidCastException. However, when I flip the types on the DataTable to nullable Int32, then the nearly identical code works properly:

```
using (TestData ds = new TestData())
{
      // Typed Rows
      ds.Models.AddModelsRow(1, 2);
      ds.Models.AddModelsRow(ds.Models.NewModelsRow()); // NULL INFO TEST
      // Untyped rows
      DataRow r = ds.Models.NewRow();
      r[0] = 4;
      r[1] = 5;
      ds.Models.Rows.Add(r);


      //query
      var list = from m in ds.Tables["Models"].AsEnumerable()
                 select new Model
                 {
                     // rest of members omitted to simplify
                     YearBegin = m.Field<int?>("YearBegin"),
                     YearEnd = m.Field<int?>("YearEnd"),
                 };
}
```

Take a look at your DataTable. You can correct your issue there. The Field cast to int? will not work unless your DataTable field matches the int? type.

Comment: I had to define every field in the target table to get this to work as advertised.  I also rewrote some underlying db sql to ensure no null columns were returned - providing defaults where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I am working against a legacy access database and the data type was stored as Integer instead on Long Integer meaning it is represented as an Int16 in the data set hence the Invalid cast exception...